# SBJsonParser boolean value on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I can't figure out how to handle this JSON value using SBJsonParser in Objective-C.
The JSON returns as `"success":true` (inside of a larger JSON object).
It parses fine and when I do a "po" on it like this `po [jsonObject objectForKey:@"success"]` the result is simply `1`.
I'm trying to figure out how to test for it in an IF statement though.
I have tried doing `== 1`, `== true`, `== TRUE`, `== YES` and `== [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` all of which return false.

How in the world do I test for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SBJSON returns booleans as `NSNumber` instances created with `+numberWithBool:` (the underlying data is `0` for false, `1` for true). You can obtain the equivalent `BOOL` value by sending them `-boolValue`. For instance,

```
BOOL success = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
if (success)
{
    NSLog(@"yay!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"oops");
}
```

Comment: Quick clarification: the reason `== [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` doesn't work is that it's testing for object identity - using `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] isEqual:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"success"]]` would also work, though I like `boolValue` better.

Comment: @Jesse Another option would be comparing against `kCFBooleanTrue` or `kCFBooleanFalse`, e.g. `([jsonObject objectForKey:@"success"] == (id)kCFBooleanTrue)`, but I prefer `-boolValue`.